# What is the Math SE logo?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

I don't know what the Math Stack Exchange logo is and was wondering if we (the users) could post ideas on a new one and have users vote for the best one... Is that a possibility or no?

Comment: Shouldn't you first figure out what the current one is? Hint: It's to the left of the big "MATHEMATICS".

Comment: @Michael: I read it as "I see the current logo, and I don't know *what that symbol or object is*".

Comment: @Zev Now I feel stupid.

Comment: Ok ok guys, so what does the current logo represent/mean?

Comment: See the "logo" section in [this thread, from when the design of the site was in development](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/963/264).

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't really like it either.

Comment: Back in the days, users posted their [ideas for site logo and name](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/285/). If you think the logo is bad, consider what it could have been...

Comment: So it seems like it was a bit of an off-the-cuff design... Searching Google Images for "math logo" shows that it's a hard problem in general. I only like the [wireframe heart with the axes through it](http://200.17.137.109:8081/xiscanoe/projeto/graduate-projects/work-with-us-ideas-for-phd-m-sc-projects/math.jpg/image). The mathematics community seems to be either notoriously unenthusiastic or to have abysmally poor taste when it comes to logo design (but usually very enthusiastic about complaining that the subject is such a hard sell to students :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logo is a set of $6$ red cubes arranged as shown below.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that the cubes are arranged in a way that couldn't actually occur in three dimensions.  I wonder if this was intentional.

Comment: Actually this logo looks like many rules of this site: a little unclear ;)